# Number generator

Tags: random, plc, st

I need to random number generator. My function have to input number to length generated output.

I have to write it in ST (language to plc drivers). In this language I haven't srand() or rand() function so I have to write it.

Anyone help me?

Answer (score 1):

If you just need pseudorandom numbers for a statistical simulation or something like that, try a [linear congruential generator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_congruential_generator) or a [multiply-with-carry generator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiply-with-carry).  Don't use these sorts of random number generators for anything security-sensitive like generating passwords or encryption keys.

Comment: Can you maybe add example code for this in codesys?